# Do Japanese have a similar expression for "the list goes on"?

Tags: translation

For example, I want to say "When I was 8, I wanted to be a go player. When was 10, I dreamed of becoming a novelist. The list goes on."

> ８歳の時、碁打ちになりたいでした。１０歳、小説家になるのが欲しいでした。「？」

Comment: I don't think になるのが欲しいでした。 is grammatical.

Comment: Also, なりたいでした should be なりたかったです, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I might say something like

> ８歳のころ...  10歳のころ...  そして、それ以降はいろいろな考えを[回]{まわ}った。

Comment: I was contemplating an answer of this sort as well but didn't want to get to fancy.

Comment: What does 考えを回る mean?

Comment: @TokyoNagoya:  What is something better?  I was going for something like `"bounced" around between different ideas`.

Answer (score 1):

> Do Japanese have a similar expression for “the list goes on”?

I don't think we have an exact equivalent but [alc辞書](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=list%20goes%20on&ref=sa) translates it as this:

> [数]{かぞ}え[上]{あ}げればきりがない。／[例]{れい}を[挙]{あ}げればきりがない。
>   まだまだたくさんの例がある。

I personally think [[枚挙]{まいきょ}にいとまがない](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9E%9A%E6%8C%99%E3%81%AB%E6%9A%87%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) is close, but it sounds quite literary.

> "When I was 8, I wanted to be a go player. When was 10, I dreamed of becoming a novelist. The list goes on."

I think you could say it like this:

> 8歳の時は、碁打ち(or プロ棋士)になりたかったです。10歳の時は、小説家になりたかったです。[他]{ほか}にもいろいろなりたいものがありました。/ 他にもなりたいものがたくさんありました。
>   or
>   8歳の時は、碁打ちになりたかったです。10歳で、小説家になりたいと思いました。その後も/その他にも、いろんな[職業]{しょくぎょう}に[憧]{あこが}れました。/ 他にもいろんなものになりたいと思いました。
>   etc...